# SMTP injection and adding a new header

Tags: smtp, command, smtpclient, code-injection, inject

I understand the basic smtp injection operation, but what if i need to add a specific headers during the injection.

As an example how can I add a new Header like "organization" during the SMTP injection?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the raw SMTP protocol, what you send after the `DATA` command is a whole email message consisting of headers and the body, so just include any header you wish in the payload.

You probably need to be more specific in your question. Example code, programming language used, libraries, environment, etc.